# yii-user-management profile 404 error

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have finally got to the admin area of yii user management but now I click on the profile link

profile/profile/view/id/1 and there is a 404 error

Once again any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing this in the config/main.php resolved the issue.

```
'modules'=>array(
    'registration' => array(),
    'avatar' => array(),
    'role' => array(),
    'messages' => array(),
    'usergroup' => array(),
    'membership' => array(),
    'profile' => array(),
    'friendship' => array(),
    'user' => array()
     ),
```

This activates the module parts.(I am new at yii)